# Handsontable formula #VALUE! error even the formula for the cell is correct

Tags: excel, handsontable

Handsontable is throwing #VALUE error even the formula is correct.

To understand my problem please replace the var data1 from this example http://jsfiddle.net/qfpfxgw5/ with the following data.

```
var data1 =
[
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","","","","","","","",""],
["","","=C13-C14","=D13-D14","=E13-E14","=F13-F14","=G13-G14","=H13-H14","=I13-I14","=SUM(C9:I9)"],
["","","985149",21651,35565,985149,548,312495,35195,"=SUM(C10:I10)"],
["","",3563546,35635,35635,75345,54245,723445,53577,"=SUM(C11:I11)"],
["","",0,0,35565,0,0,312495,0,"=SUM(C12:I12)"],
["","",3563546,35635,"=D13+E10+E12","=E13+F10+F12","=G12+G10+F13","=H12+H10+G13","=I12+I10+H13","=SUM(C13:I13)"],
["","",3563546,35635,"=D14+E11","=E14+F11","=F14+G11","=G14+H11","=H14+I11","=SUM(C14:I14)"],
["","",50,50,50,50,50,50,50,"=SUM(C15:I15)"],
["","",3550,3550,3621,4800,3550,3550,3300,"=SUM(C16:I16)"],
["","",8,8,8,8,8,8,8,"=SUM(C17:I17)"]
];
```

And run.

You will see #VALUE! error on E9,F9 and so on.

We have

```
E9=E13-E14;  
E13=D13+E10+E12;  and
E14=D14+E11
```

why doesn't it give the expected output until i again reset the value of E9=E13-E14. What should be the another solution to solve it ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume because those cells also have formulas attached to them. So for some reason if doesn't render becuase of this.

Solution?, not sure, I tried getting a cell with a formula from other cells further up to see if maybe once they rendered, the cells below would work, but it didnt.

Edit: I'm actually looking into something similar and came up with a not so pretty solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/qfpfxgw5/2/

Basically if you are referencing a value from a cell which also has a function associated with it, it wont work.

So, to make it work, you have to include the actual formula from that other cell within the formula for your current cell.

example:

```
cellA13: = E13-E14
cellE13: = SUM(B2,B3)
cellE14: = 100
```

This doesnt work, but if you change it to this:

```
cellA13: =SUM((SUM(B2,B3))-E14)
cellE13: =SUM(B2,B3)
cellE14: =100
```

My example above does something similar and it worked.

Ugly... but i dont know how else to make it work.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?
As ugly as it may be, it does work, and i dont currently know of any other workaround to the issue.